# Filter an array of object to get the largest remaining capacity

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Given I have an array of object such as

```
let discList = [{
"id" : 1,
"capacity" : 100,
"used" : 50
}, {
"id" : 2,
"capacity" : 200,
"used" : 10
}, {
"id" : 3,
"capacity" : 50,
"used" : 10}]
```

Is there a way to filter this array such that I get the item for the largest remaining capacity?

remainingCapacity = capacity - used;

In the above example, I'm hoping to get the 2nd item. Since

```
1st item = 100-50 = 50
2nd item = 200-10 = 190
3rd item = 50-10 = 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the easiest way to go. Gradually loop through the array, and keep replacing the object with the highest object. By the end of the array, you'll have the max:

```js
let discList = [{
  "id" : 1,
  "capacity" : 100,
  "used" : 50
  }, {
  "id" : 2,
  "capacity" : 200,
  "used" : 10
  }, {
  "id" : 3,
  "capacity" : 50,
  "used" : 10
}]

var max = discList.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.capacity - prev.used > current.capacity - current.used) ? prev : current
});

console.log(max);
```

I'd avoid going the sorting route, as it causes a lot of unnecessary comparisons, and will get more costly the greater the size of the array (Due to the steps required to reorder all the elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let discList = [{
  "id" : 1,
  "capacity" : 100,
  "used" : 50
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "capacity" : 200,
  "used" : 10
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "capacity" : 50,
  "used" : 10}
];

const mostRemainingCapacity = discList.reduce((a, e) => 
  e.capacity - e.used > a.capacity - a.used ? e : a, 
  {capacity: -Infinity, used: Infinity}
);

console.log(mostRemainingCapacity);
```

#### Explanation

Begin reduction with an object that has the worst possible remaining capacity, namely, negative infinity capacity and infinity space used. Iterating over each element, compare its remaining capacity to the best so far and return the better of the two.

Answer (score 1):

should be easy with reduce

```js
const discList = [{
  "id": 1,
  "capacity": 100,
  "used": 50
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "capacity": 200,
  "used": 10
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "capacity": 50,
  "used": 10
}];

console.log(discList.reduce((max, {capacity, used}) => {
  return Math.max(max, capacity - used);
}, 0));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just get's the max capacity, not the actual object. How does this have 2 upvotes?